# Twilio Remote video not visible

Tags: angular, safari, twilio, twilio-video

I am using twilio for P2P video call in angular. Video call is working fine between Chrome 2 chrome but not between safari to chrome. When using safari, remote participant's video & audio is not visible in safari. I have already tried to change codec to H264 but didn't worked.

Here I am attaching github repository link to reproduce scenario.

https://github.com/ashishgehlot/Twilio-issue-reporduction

I also investigated that below code always return false in safari case.

```
participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
          if (publication.isSubscribed) { // always false
```

and it never logged in console

```
      publication.on('subscribed', track => {
        console.log('==================subscribed'); // not triggered
```

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: I managed to fix this issue with twilio's help. You just need to add these polyfills for safari.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-user-media';
import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection';

Comment: is there any forum where they provide support?, on GitHub i have opened some issues haven't got any answer yet!

Comment: You can open support ticket at twilio's site.https://www.twilio.com/console/support/tickets/create

Comment: Thanks man appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please check this function.

```
  participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
      if (publication.isSubscribed)
        console.log(publication.track);

      if (!publication.isSubscribed)
        publication.on('subscribed', track => {
          console.log(track);
        });
    });
```

Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

These polyfills solved my problem.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-user-media';
import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection';
```